# Download interrupted on Android, but finished on Windows

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am using [Speed-Test-Lib](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/speed-test-lib) for download speed test.

When I try **DownloadFileExample.java** with host="**download.thinkbroadband.com**" & uri="**/20MB.zip**", from PC, the file is downloaded correctly.

But when I try the **android example** with the same host&uri on mobile, the file **starts downloading and then stopped** after downloading some Mega Bytes, as if the host is waiting something, then off course timeout is raised.

The download rate of the mobile is about 2.4Mbps and, for PC I used the mobile as a hotspot.

I know that **the issue is not related to the library** that I use, since I also tried coding myself once using sockets and another using HTTPUrlConnection, but with the same issue.

Can any one help me know what is the reason for this issue.

**DownloadFileExample.java**

```
package fr.bmartel.speedtest.examples;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import fr.bmartel.speedtest.SpeedTestReport;
import fr.bmartel.speedtest.SpeedTestSocket;
import fr.bmartel.speedtest.inter.ISpeedTestListener;
import fr.bmartel.speedtest.model.SpeedTestError;
import fr.bmartel.speedtest.model.SpeedTestMode;

/**
 * Download file Speed Test example.
 *
 * @author Bertrand Martel
 */
public class DownloadFileExample {

/**
 * socket timeout used in ms.
 */
private final static int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;

/**
 * speed examples server host name.
 */
private final static String SPEED_TEST_SERVER_HOST = "download.thinkbroadband.com";

/**
 * spedd examples server uri.
 */
private final static String SPEED_TEST_SERVER_URI_DL = "/20MB.zip";

/**
 * speed examples server port.
 */
private final static int SPEED_TEST_SERVER_PORT = 80;

/**
 * logger.
 */
private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(DownloadFileExample.class.getName());

/**
 * Download file example main.
 *
 * @param args no args required
 */
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    // instantiate speed examples
    final SpeedTestSocket speedTestSocket = new SpeedTestSocket();

    //set timeout for download
    speedTestSocket.setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

    // add a listener to wait for speed examples completion and progress
    speedTestSocket.addSpeedTestListener(new ISpeedTestListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadFinished(final SpeedTestReport report) {

            LogUtils.logFinishedTask(SpeedTestMode.DOWNLOAD, report.getTotalPacketSize(),
                    report.getTransferRateBit(),
                    report.getTransferRateOctet(), LOGGER);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDownloadError(final SpeedTestError speedTestError, final String errorMessage) {
            if (LOGGER.isErrorEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.error("Download error " + speedTestError + " : " + errorMessage);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUploadFinished(final SpeedTestReport report) {

            LogUtils.logFinishedTask(SpeedTestMode.UPLOAD, report.getTotalPacketSize(),
                    report.getTransferRateBit(),
                    report.getTransferRateOctet(), LOGGER);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUploadError(final SpeedTestError speedTestError, final String errorMessage) {
            if (LOGGER.isErrorEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.error("Upload error " + speedTestError + " : " + errorMessage);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownloadProgress(final float percent, final SpeedTestReport downloadReport) {

            LogUtils.logSpeedTestReport(downloadReport, LOGGER);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUploadProgress(final float percent, final SpeedTestReport uploadReport) {

            LogUtils.logSpeedTestReport(uploadReport, LOGGER);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInterruption() {
            //triggered when forceStopTask is called
        }
    });

    speedTestSocket.startDownload(SPEED_TEST_SERVER_HOST, SPEED_TEST_SERVER_PORT, SPEED_TEST_SERVER_URI_DL);
    }
}
```

**Using Android (AsyncTask):**

```
package ac.mohammad.com.tmpapp2;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import fr.bmartel.speedtest.SpeedTestReport;
import fr.bmartel.speedtest.SpeedTestSocket;
import fr.bmartel.speedtest.inter.ISpeedTestListener;
import fr.bmartel.speedtest.model.SpeedTestError;

/**
 * Created on 014 2/14/2017.
 */

public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Double, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... progress) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        Log.d("speedtest","Finish");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        SpeedTestSocket speedTestSocket = new SpeedTestSocket();

        // add a listener to wait for speedtest completion and progress
        speedTestSocket.addSpeedTestListener(new ISpeedTestListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDownloadFinished(SpeedTestReport report) {
                // called when download is finished
                Log.v("speedtest", "[DL FINISHED] rate in octet/s : " + report.getTransferRateOctet());
                Log.v("speedtest", "[DL FINISHED] rate in bit/s   : " + report.getTransferRateBit());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDownloadError(SpeedTestError speedTestError, String errorMessage) {
                // called when a download error occur
                Log.v("speedtest", "[DL Error] : " + errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUploadFinished(SpeedTestReport report) {
                // called when an upload is finished
                Log.v("speedtest", "[UL FINISHED] rate in octet/s : " + report.getTransferRateOctet());
                Log.v("speedtest", "[UL FINISHED] rate in bit/s   : " + report.getTransferRateBit());
            }

            @Override
            public void onUploadError(SpeedTestError speedTestError, String errorMessage) {
                // called when an upload error occur
                Log.v("speedtest", "[UL Error] : " + errorMessage);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDownloadProgress(float percent, SpeedTestReport report) {
                // called to notify download progress
                Log.v("speedtest", "[DL PROGRESS] progress : " + percent + "%");
                long curTime =System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

            @Override
            public void onUploadProgress(float percent, SpeedTestReport report) {
                // called to notify upload progress
                Log.v("speedtest", "[UL PROGRESS] progress : " + percent + "%");
                Log.v("speedtest", "[UL PROGRESS] rate in bit/s   : " + report.getTransferRateBit());
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterruption() {
                // triggered when forceStopTask is called
                Log.v("speedtest", "[Forced Stop]");
            }
        });

        speedTestSocket.startDownload("download.thinkbroadband.com", "/20MB.zip");
        return null;
    }
}
```

The android AsyncTask is called like this:

```
new TestTask().execute();
```

Comment: On Android you need an AsyncTask? Please try without.

Comment: `for PC I used the mobile as a hotspot.`. Interesting.

Comment: `I know that the issue is not related to the library that I use, since I also tried coding myself once using sockets and another using HTTPUrlConnection, but with the same issue.`. Strange. I would definitely blame the library then.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sure, I need AsyncTask or separate thread for network operations, otherwise exception **NetworkOnMainThreadException** will raise.

Comment: Well did you try without?

Comment: Yes, without AsyncTask, it raised exception **NetworkOnMainThreadException**